# Log MySQL queries by database

Tags: mysql, database, logging

I'm aware I can set MySQL up to temporarily log all queries made into a table, for instance with the queries:

```
SET GLOBAL log_output = 'TABLE';
SET GLOBAL general_log = 'ON';
```

A new table called `mysql.general_log` will be created with a log of everything going trough MySQL. This is great for debugging proposes, however is there a way I can have a different log table for each database?

For example, database `wordpress`should have the log at `wordpress.general_log`. Database `myawesomeapp` should log to `myawesomeapp.general_log` is this possible? How?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately that's not possible. You would have to have two different database instances to accomplish that.